# Python: Conversión de un string a tipo lista sin tener los caracteres separados

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista, conversión-de-tipos

Quiero convertir un string a una lista sin que me separe los carácteres.
Yo puedo hacer:

```
cadena = "hola"
```

Si ahora hago:

```
list(cadena)
```

La respuesta del interprete es:

```
  ['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']
```

Pero supongamos que yo quiero tener esta otra respuesta:

```
['hola']
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo sin hacer: `lista = ["hola"]`?
¿Hay algo así como una función que me junte todos los carácteres separados en una lista a una lista de un solo string? ¿O una función que me junte todos los elementos ya sean números y cadenas de una lista y me los presente como una cadena de una lista de un solo elemento, siendo ese elemento dicha cadena?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplemente mete la variable dentro de `[]`:

```
>>> cadena = "hola"
>>> lista = [cadena]
>>> lista
['hola']
```

A diferencia de usar `list()` que construye la lista iterando sobre la cadena, esto equivale a:

```
>>> cadena = "hola"
>>> lista = []
>>> lista.append(cadena)
>>> lista
['hola']
```

El método que planteas en tu autorespuesta funciona, pero usar el contructor de `list()` y luego el método `join()` es mucho más ineficiente ya que primero iteras sobre la cadena para separarla en caracteres para luego iterar sobre la lista de caracteres para pasarla de nuevo a una cadena.

Esta es la forma más sencilla y directa de hacerlo, si deseas agregar varias cadenas:

```
>>> cadena1 = "Hola"
>>> cadena2 = 'mundo'
>>> cadena3 = 'Python'
>>> lista = [cadena1, cadena2, cadena3]
>>> lista
['Hola', 'mundo', 'Python']
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues la respuesta de @FJSevilla es buena pero pues para que su respuesta funcione tiene que tener ya todas los string listo que vas a meter en la lista pero que pasa si quieres meter uno a uno y en diferentes momentos del script.

En ese caso lo mejor seria utilizar la funcion **append**

Vamos al codigo

```
  hola ="juan"
  lista=[]
  lista.append(hola)
  print(lista)
  >>['juan']
  lista.append("hola mundo")
  print(lista)
  >>['juan', 'hola mundo']
```

Espero que te sirva @Mr. Baldan

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta, yo quiero hacer precisamente lo contrario a formar una lista con varios elementos, quiero tener una lista con un solo elemento

Answer (score 0):

Voy a usar el método join:

```
>>> lista2=list(cadena)
>>> lista2
['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']
>>> separador =""
>>> lista3 = [separador.join(lista2)]
>>> lista3
['hola']
```